# What happens if we take out two diodes from diode bridge?

Tags: bridge-rectifier

In all textbooks diode bridge that transforms AC to DC is drawn as having 4 diodes like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDTuUY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I wonder, what would happen if we replace, for example, D1 and D4 with usual wires? In order for current to flow, the circuit has to be closed. However, the diodes D2 and D3 should stop the current from flowing through the lamp in the wrong direction.

Nowhere could I find full explanation of why isn't that so and in fact all four diodes are needed.

Comment: what is a `usual wire`?

Comment: If you remove D1 and D4, you short-circuit the power supply.  It is possible to make rectifiers with only one or two diodes - if you replace D4 with a wire, and delete D1 and D3, D2 will serve as a half-wave rectifier.

Comment: *Nowhere could I find full explanation of why isn't that so and in fact all four diodes are needed.* I don't think you need a website to tell you that in every way you short a voltage supply it won't deliver power to your load. That should be obvious from the very basics of electronic circuits.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Moreover, if they seem unnecessary then it can't be clear to you how a fw rectifier works in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fToQqy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. D1 and D4 have been replaced with wires. LAMP1 has been disconnected for clarity.*

It should be obvious from the modified schematic that (D4) and (D1) have short-circuited your AC supply. The lamp will never light (even if connected) and if the transformer is inadequately fused it will overheat and, possibly, catch fire.

> Nowhere could I find full explanation of why isn't that so and in fact all four diodes are needed.

Bookmark this page!

Answer (score 6):

Some common rectifier circuits, and your proposal at number 4,

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7Vdon.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I like this answer best +1

Answer (score 0):

If you replace D1 and D4 with wires you will have a direct path that will short the ac supply (V1).

It is not unusual in measurement applications (eg voltmeters) to use a bridge arrangement with resistors replacing two of the diodes. This has the advantage of reducing the diode drop to that of a single diode rather than two diode drops, so it improves linearity at low voltages.